# Does triggering a button from within a function leave something on the stack?

Tags: swift, button, triggers, stack

User is playing a game against the computer. After user does something, (e.g. in button-pressed routine called **User Plays**), a button called **Computer Play** is enabled. When user presses it, the computer plays, and then enables **user play**. All routines essentially finish and wait for user input.

If, instead, I trigger the **Computer Play** button automatically from the bottom of the **user plays** routine, will I leave something on the stack? Will I be building up a huge series of nested functions and eventually run out of stack space?

Comment: Are you talking about a method calling another method that in turn calls the first method? As inokey mentions in his answer, that would be recursive, and you could cause infinite recursion and a **STACK OVERFLOW** in that case. You need to explain what you're doing in more detail.

Comment: An attempt to clarify. Suppose I'm coding checkers. There's a clickOnSquare routine. User clicks (on a legal square, etc) and the piece moves. Now it's computer's turn. User presses "Move" button and the computer does it. The clickOnSquare routine ended, and so did the movePressed routine. However, suppose just trigger the buttonPressed routine at the bottom of that clickOnEmptySquare routine. Now the computer makes its move automatically. Did that clickOnSquare routine actually end, or when user makes the next move (i.e. clicksOnSquare), was something left on the stack?

Comment: As I indicated in my answer, nothing about calling an IBAction method from code instead of triggering it in response to a user tap has any effect on memory. There's no "leaving stuff on the stack" as a result of calling the IBAction from other code. Period.

Comment: If you're talking about recursion then you need to be clear about that. Your comment "clarifying" your question doesn't really clarify much. You don't indicate which methods are IBAction methods triggered by button taps, or what methods are called by other code, or what the calling sequence is.

Comment: Edit your question to show your code that calls your different methods so we can see if you are calling it recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Button IBAction methods are methods like any other. They get called, they execute their code, and they return. Their local variables get allocated on the stack, and then get popped off the stack when the function returns.

If you have memory leaks in your IBAction method they will occur whether the method is called from a button press or from another method.

If you don't have memory leaks, calling a button's IBAction method from another method won't cause a memory leak.

### EDIT:

Note that if you have endlessly recursive code (where a method calls itself repeatedly, or method A calls method B which calls method A which calls method B and so on forever) then you can endlessly allocate more and more stack memory until you have a **stack overflow** and crash your program. However, you'll know about that pretty quickly. Your app will freeze for a few seconds and then crash, every time you go into endless recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you work with a recursion there's a slight chance something might go wrong. Your question could be answered differently based on *how* your code is executed on practice.

Do you use escaping callbacks or you just call your methods from within each other and so on. Please provide some code or at least pseudo version of it. The general answer for this will be - **yes**. You have a risk to run out of stack space if your recursion call is potentially infinite.

Comment: The OP did not mention recursion.

Comment: @DuncanC I've seen your answer and it got me thinking, I even thought of deleting my answer but I couldn't get to the decision. It feels like the call might be recursive (from the current description). I'll see if the OP updates answer or comments on that to decide if I'm wrong and have to delete my answer.

Comment: Re-reading the OPs question I see your point. He could be describing a recursive call, or not. It' isn't clear.